# Is there any way to make fileinput.input() with openhook=hook_compressed performant?

Tags: python, performance, file-io, gzip

It seems that `fileinput.input` is at least twice as slow as `zcat`, even with buffering set. **Question: Is there anything I can do to make it performant, without writing a bunch of code?** What I did to test it was to take data from urandom,

```
"""generate.py"""
import base64
with open('/dev/urandom', 'rb') as f:
    for _ in xrange(102400):
        print(base64.b64encode(f.read(1024)))
```

run this and pipe the output through gzip,

```
> python generate.py | gzip - > test_input.gz
```

### zcat time

```
> time zcat test_input.gz > /dev/null
zcat test_input.gz > /dev/null  1.56s user 0.02s system 99% cpu 1.576 total
```

### fileinput time

```
> time python -c 'import fileinput; list(fileinput.input(files=["test_input.gz"], openhook=fileinput.hook_compressed))'
python -c   3.13s user 0.16s system 99% cpu 3.293 total
```

This isn't just `fileinput.input()` being slow, since when it reads from stdin it's fine,

```
> time zcat test_input.gz | python -c 'import fileinput; list(fileinput.input())'
zcat test_input.gz  1.64s user 0.04s system 96% cpu 1.736 total
python -c 'import fileinput; list(fileinput.input())'  0.39s user 0.17s system 31% cpu 1.800 total
```

I messed with `bufsize=`, but no luck.

### writing a lot of code

I poked around google thinking `gzip` itself was slow, and found if I do some manual buffering it's fine,

```
"""read_buffered_manual.py"""
import gzip

def input_buffered_manual(filename, buf_size=32 * 1024):
    fd = gzip.open(filename)
    try:
        remaining = ''
        while True:
            input_ = fd.read(buf_size)
            if not input_:
                if remaining:
                    yield remaining
                return

            lines = input_.split('\n')
            lines[0] = remaining + lines[0]
            remaining = lines.pop()
            for line in lines:
                yield line
    finally:
        fd.close()

for line in input_buffered_manual("test_input.gz"):
    print line
```

this is fast, in fact even faster than zcat,

```
> time python read_buffered_manual.py > /dev/null
python read_buffered_manual.py > /dev/null  1.40s user 0.04s system 99% cpu 1.461 total
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use specialized tooling:

```
import gzip
import sys
import shutil

for filename in ["test_input.gz"]:
    with gzip.open(filename) as file:
        shutil.copyfileobj(file, sys.stdout)
```

That's pretty fast.

Comment: Thanks, but I kinda want to use something like fileinput ... fileinput is a convenient module for line-by-line processing of data specified on the command line.